# Extracting levels from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

For extracting levels from a data.table, is the standard way to lapply over the `data.table` as a list or do it inside the brackets somehow?

For example, using the `npk` builtin data, I know that the first 4 columns are factors and I want to extract the levels.

```
dat <- as.data.table(npk)
```

This is what I want, a list of the levels

```
levs <- lapply(dat[,1:4,with=FALSE], levels)
```

But, am I missing the `data.table` way that would be something like this? (this isnt right though because it repeats the levels to match the longest one).

```
levs2 <- dat[, lapply(.SD, levels), .SDcols=names(dat)[1:4]]
```

ps. sorry if this seems dumb, I am just trying to pick up the proper data.table idioms.

Comment: `dat[, .(Var=names(.SD), levs=lapply(.SD,levels)), .SDcols=names(dat)[1:4] ]` if you want to get a bit of a convoluted `data.table` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example seems reasonable to me, and I don't think that you can do it within the brackets of the data.table, as the return type should be a list.

Another option is `Filter(Negate(is.null),lapply(DT,levels))`, which has the added benefit of not needing to know which columns are factors beforehand

Comment: @rawr fair point, but I would rather the computer do that then manually inspect the list myself. Can't imagine the cost is that significant. Would the levels function test the vector type first and then cry `NULL`, or test every element of the vector. Alternatively said, would the cost increase with more rows?

Comment: rows or columns? `levels` doesn't even look at the rows, just the attributes. I don't use data table but I imagine it would be more efficient to index the columns which are factors and then get the levels assuming that data table does column subsetting by reference as well. basically the lapply is the slow bit

Comment: @rawr I meant rows. And you are right (proven with `testa <- runif(100000000);testb <- runif(2);microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a = levels(testa), b = levels(testb))`) All that means is that the cost only scales with columns, not rows. So I'd rather test all the columns using a generic solution, then have to manually identify each column (which is a human problem that also scales with the number of columns).

Comment: Something like `lapply(Filter(is.factor,DT), levels)` is more intuitive to me, and perhaps more general.